# I was trying to break Haskell and got an "Inaccessiable code" error from GHC. What does it mean?

Tags: haskell, types, compiler-errors, dependent-type

So, I had the following code:

```
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs #-}

import Data.Coerce
import Data.Functor.Fixedpoint --Although I'm not using these yet, they provide "context"

data Refl a b where
    Refl :: Refl a a

weird :: Refl a [a] -> a
weird Refl = [[], [[], []]]
```

I think you can see where I am going. If not, what I am trying to do is to force Haskell into thinking that `a` and `[a]` are the same type by giving it the `Refl` argument. This will allow me to do shenanigans. When I to compile it, `ghci` gives me this error:

```
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( pad'.hs, interpreted )

pad'.hs:9:7:
    Couldn't match type ‘a’ with ‘[a]’
      ‘a’ is a rigid type variable bound by
          the type signature for weird :: Refl a [a] -> [a] at pad'.hs:8:10
    Inaccessible code in
      a pattern with constructor
        Refl :: forall a. Refl a a,
      in an equation for ‘weird’
    Relevant bindings include
      weird :: Refl a [a] -> [a] (bound at pad'.hs:9:1)
    In the pattern: Refl
    In an equation for ‘weird’: weird Refl = [[], [[], []]]
Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

What does `Inaccessible code` mean? In general, are there any resources related to what I'm trying to do?

Comment: The code is "inaccessible" because even if you compile that function, pretending there is no type error, nothing calling your function will ever reach that code, because it is not well typed (so any application which would use it would not be well typed).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It simply means that there's no way to call function `weird` with a non-bottom argument (i.e., with a *terminating*, non exception-raising expression).

This is because no constructor (or more precisely, no WHNF) can ever have `Refl a [a]` as its type. Indeed, the types `a` and `[a]` are surely different, whatever `a` might be (and this can be checked during unification).

Since this is more often than not a source of a programming error, GHC errors out to loudly complain to the programmer.

If taking an "impossible" input is what you really wanted to do, use this instead:

```
{-# LANGUAGE EmptyCase #-}
weird :: Refl a [a] -> a
weird x = case x of { }
```

or even

```
{-# LANGUAGE EmptyCase #-}
weird :: Refl a [a] -> b
weird x = case x of { }
```

Indeed, `weird` can actually produce any type at all! Being impossible to call, it can claim any type for its output. This follows the logical principle "ex falso quod libet": from a false premise (e.g. that `a` and `[a]` are the same type) you can deduce whatever you wish.

Final note, since you import `Data.Functor.Fixedpoint`, I guess you want to use `Fix []`. Well, that is *isomorphic* to `[Fix []]` -- but not equal! So, again, you can't have a non-bottom expression of type `Refl (Fix []) [Fix []]`.

Comment: I was going to use `coerce`, from `Data.Coerce`. It can converts newtypes, if when buried inside of other types. For example, `coerce` can take on the type `coerce::Maybe (Fix []) -> Maybe [Fix []]`.

Comment: Also, is there anyway to get GHC to "suppress" this error?

Comment: @PyRulez Ah, `coerce`! If that works, it looks pretty bad. I hope GHC infers the right role to `Refl` to forbid it. About the error: I don't think it can be suppressed: why do you want to keep the code for an "impossible" case? If that's possible that's another issue, IMHO, that should be fixed...

Comment: @PyRulez By default, `Refl` arguments have type roles "nominal, nominal", so `coerce` does not work. Whew.

Comment: I actually did try it later. When I run `coerce Refl :: Refl (Fix []) [Fix []]`, it just says it can't match `Fix []` and `[Fix []]`. Do you know the "rules" surrounding coerce?

Comment: @PyRulez Not precisely, it has to do with [type roles](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/roles.html). Nominal roles can not be coerced. Others can. See also the [coercion rules](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/libraries/base-4.8.1.0/Data-Coerce.html)

Comment: @PyRulez You can turn the error into a mere warning with `-fdefer-type-errors`, though this will apply to all other type errors in the file as well.